# How do i override default scope for mongoid with rails_admin?

Tags: mongoid, rails-admin

Currently I have a default_scope set for my class, but I want rails_admin to perform the list-query using .unscoped

Is there any way to make this happen? I don't see a way to override query that rails_admin executes.

Answer (score 1):

You can name scopes that rails_admin makes available for the list action, they will show up as tabs in the list action:

```
list do
   scopes [:unscoped, :all, :any_other_scope]
end
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use **unscoped**:

From mongoid doc:

```
Band.unscoped.where(name: "Depeche Mode")
Band.unscoped do
  Band.where(name: "Depeche Mode")
end
```

Please refer to:
[mongoid scoping](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#scoping)

Comment: I understand how to do it in mongoid, just dont know how to plug that in with rails_admin.